# Display image in ImageControl?

Tags: model-view-controller

I am developing one MVC project for simple image upload , I successfully stored Image on local drive and image path in database, my question is how do I retrieve the image stored on local drive using path stored in database?

Comment: What language / framework / platform are you using? The [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) can be applied to almost any software written in any language on any operating system.

Comment: @DaveBoltman c# language ,4.5 framework and MVC 4